# How to extract "name" and the "runs" from this list of objects

Tags: javascript, json

So here is have the function I made. I want to extract the `names` in an array and the `runs` of the respective teams so I can use them as a response to display them in a graph.

```
function unpack(obj, key) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        var collection = [];
        var collections = [];
        for (var k in obj) {
            collection.push(obj[k]);
        }
        console.log(collection);
        return collection;
    });
}
```

This is the list of objects

```
[
{
 name: "Scotland",
 stats: {
 runs: 16135,
 wickets_taken: 1,
 matches_played: 354
 }
},
{
name: "Pakistan",
stats: {
 runs: 70900,
 wickets_taken: 43,
 matches_played: 1066
 }
},
{
 name: "West Indies",
 stats: {
  runs: 61300,
  wickets_taken: 280,
  matches_played: 739
  }
 },
 {
  name: "Sri Lanka",
  stats: {
   runs: 108242,
   wickets_taken: 741,
   matches_played: 1049
    }
  }]
```

Comment: You want 2 different arrays? or a single array?

Comment: I wanted two different arrays, so that i can use them separate ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the variable in which your object is stored is obj

```
function getData() {
        var names = [];
        var runs = [];
        obj.forEach(function(item) {
            names.push(item.name);
            runs.push(item.stats.runs);
        });
        return {
            runs: runs,
            names: names,
        }
    }
    //access them outside as:
var data = getData();
var names = data.names; //accessing name and run array returned from fxn
var runs = data.runs;
```

Comment: console says obj is not defined. and my object is an api endpoint. so what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with for loop

```js
var dataObj = [
    {
     name: "Scotland",
     stats: {
     runs: 16135,
     wickets_taken: 1,
     matches_played: 354
     }
    },
    {
    name: "Pakistan",
    stats: {
     runs: 70900,
     wickets_taken: 43,
     matches_played: 1066
     }
    },
    {
     name: "West Indies",
     stats: {
      runs: 61300,
      wickets_taken: 280,
      matches_played: 739
      }
     },
     {
      name: "Sri Lanka",
      stats: {
       runs: 108242,
       wickets_taken: 741,
       matches_played: 1049
     }
      }
    ];

var names = [];
var runs = [];

for(var i= 0; i<  dataObj.length; i++) 
{
  names.push(dataObj[i].name);
  runs.push(dataObj[i].stats.runs);
}
 
console.log('NAMES', names);
console.log('RUNS',runs);
```